# CQWP filter for empty column

Tags: 2010, content-query-web-part

Im using a CQWP and need to display all items that have a column that is empty. The column is a lookup but I've tried a normal (single line of text) column but cqwp shows no filtering for null or empty values.

Comment: Well, i guess you could try with `0;#` as this is the equivalent to a empty lookup column.

Comment: Tried  equal 0;# but doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Workaround - create new Calculated column "Display".

Formula should be: *=IF(LEN(LookupCol)=0;"Yes";"No")*.

Eventually, make a filter based on Display column: Show items when Display is equal to Yes.

Answer (score 0):

To further Tomislav's answer, set the calculated column to return Yes/No:

```
=IF(LEN(LookupCol)=0,1,0)
```

Then filter the CQWP with Display = 1

Edit: This doesn't work because apparently the generated CAML Query always sets the field type to text for calculated columns, according to this: https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/issues/758